# How can I count the number of tcp retransmissions in a pcap file using python?

Tags: python, filter, pcap

I have some pcap files I want to count the number of tcp retransmissions on a per-flow basis.  Does anyone knows of a python module I could leverage for this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of something that will do the count for you, but there are a couple ways to open pcap files in Python. I like scapy, http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/

there is also pypcap http://code.google.com/p/pypcap/ and while i've never used it, the dirtbags.net implementation looks interesting. It does not use the pcap libs which is kind of cool. http://dirtbags.net/py-pcap.html

Answer (score 2):

Not enough reputation points to post this as a comment, but [tshark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) supports exporting of pcap files to xml using the `-T` option (with either the `pdml` or `psml` argument):

```
tshark -T pdml -r {infile} >{outfile}
```

One you have the xml files, you can easily parse them with one of the many libraries available out there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a python subprocess to call tshark. tshark is the console version of [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). tshark/wireshark have many options to filter and analyse pcaps. Counting retransmission on a per flow basis could be archived like this:

```
tshark -T fields -e tcp.stream -e frame.number -r cap.pcapng 'tcp.analysis.retransmission'
```